# MongoDb: Find all (sub)documents in all collections with a particular field

Tags: mongodb

I need to find all Documents and Sub-Documents which contain a particular field, e.g. the field `staffNumber` might be a field in a `employees` collections Document as well as in a `managers`-Collections Sub-Documents.
I want to search all Documents of all types for `staffNumber` fields without knowing which collection contains possible matches.

Comment: What is the structure of your documents?

Comment: It must be considered unknown.

Comment: So search to see if a field `staffNumber` exists somewhere in a document?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's setup some test data to start with:

```
> db.test.drop()
true
> db.test.insert({test:true})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({test:true, staffNumber: 1234})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({test:true, other: {staffNumber: 1234}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.insert({test:true, other1: { other2: {staffNumber: 1234}}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
```

Then we can use the $where operator to run a bit of javascript:

```
db.test.find( { $where: function() {
   function hasProp(obj, prop) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (p === prop && obj[p] !== "" && obj[p] !== undefined && obj[p] !== null) {
                return obj;
            } else if (obj[p] instanceof Object && hasProp(obj[p], prop)) {
                return obj[p];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
   }
   return hasProp(this, "staffNumber");
} } );
```

This will then yeild the following results:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d4146be02da4d3fc1940a"), "test" : true, "staffNumber" : 1234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d4153be02da4d3fc1940b"), "test" : true, "other" : { "staffNumber" : 1234 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a9d4166be02da4d3fc1940c"), "test" : true, "other1" : { "other2" : { "staffNumber" : 1234 } } }
```

More reading on `$where` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: When testing it with several field names the command quits without any output or errors. I tried fields that definitely exist.

Comment: Just noticed `test` is the name of the collection not the database. Is it possible to get this at db level?

Comment: You can use `db.getSiblingDB("other-database")`